# opentok - archiving to AWS folder fails

Tags: amazon-s3, opentok, tokbox

I simply call the startArchive / stopArchive methods opentok.
Then I check the AWS folder to see if the files are successfully recorded. 
However, for some cases, the JSON created for the archive is not complete, and there is no video file saved at all. 
Any idea how to pinpoint the reason for this issue?

Example JSON - a successful one;

```
 "createdAt" : 1494502861651,
 "files" : [
  {
     "connectionData" : "",
     "filename" : "xxxx.webm",
     "size" : 204288,
     "startTimeOffset" : 571,
     "stopTimeOffset" : 15469,
     "streamId" : "xxxxx-5944-43cd-85ff-1904a54e04ca",
     "videoType" : "camera"
        }
     ],
         "id" : "1xxxx1-3c75-48dc-b2e5-19714b911967",
       "name" : "Shamaleyte",
       "sessionId" : "2_MX40NTYwMjxxxx-
         MTQ5MzkwNDMzNTg3NX5XUWRxxxxBVjYrUE5DTUZwUzhCNnFwdi9-fg"
    }
```

Example JSON - a broken one; as you can observe, there is no filename, size, and stopTimeOffset parameters in this JSON.

```
 "createdAt" : 1494502861651,
 "files" : [
  {
     "connectionData" : "",        
     "startTimeOffset" : 571,        
     "streamId" : "xxxxx-5944-43cd-85ff-1904a54e04ca",
     "videoType" : "camera"
        }
     ],
         "id" : "1xxxx1-3c75-48dc-b2e5-19714b911967",
       "name" : "Shamaleyte",
       "sessionId" : "2_MX40NTYwMjxxxx-
         MTQ5MzkwNDMzNTg3NX5XUWRxxxxBVjYrUE5DTUZwUzhCNnFwdi9-fg"
    }
```

So it seems like that the stopArchiving somehow fails to upload the webm file because of a reason. How could I debug it?

PS : I checked the [opentok UI](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/) in order to see the status of the archiving and it says "uploaded" but the weird thing is that the details are as the following;

**Length       Size**

00:00:00    0.00MB

Why so?

Answer (score 0):

This looks identical to a known issue in Opentok platform that should be fixed on our next release, currently just about to be deployed. This should not reproduce once TB next deployment is complete.